# Is there any processes that I can disable to shorten the booting time?

Tags: release-loki, boot

```
systemd-analyze blame
           630ms ufw.service
           405ms dev-sda2.device
           354ms systemd-logind.service
           350ms pantheon-parental-controls.service
           244ms udisks2.service
           231ms lightdm.service
           230ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           199ms upower.service
           193ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           171ms NetworkManager.service
           171ms systemd-rfkill.service
           162ms systemd-hostnamed.service
           156ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           150ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           148ms systemd-localed.service
           143ms apparmor.service
           139ms gpu-manager.service
           137ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           133ms systemd-resolved.service
           120ms keyboard-setup.service
           100ms ModemManager.service
            95ms swapfile.swap
            94ms accounts-daemon.service
            94ms grub-common.service
            75ms thermald.service
            66ms speech-dispatcher.service
            62ms systemd-timedated.service
```

My startup finished in 6.064s (firmware) + 5.632s (loader) + 4.799s (kernel) + 1.391s (userspace) = 17.888s
graphical.target reached after 1.382s in userspace

Also, is the firewall really necessary? I'll be mostly working while connected to my home WiFi and some Python studies at Cafés(public WiFi) etc.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only service/daemon I see in your list you could disable safely is
`pantheon-parental-controls.service`... in case you're an adult :P

I'm not sure about the firewall service, maybe is needed elsewhere. It needs more research.

Anyway is better to use this command not the one you used

`sudo systemd-anaylze plot > boot.svg`

, then upload boot.svg that way we can see which service is really slowing down your machine, and of course one you don't need and is safe to disable.

---

### Use at your own risk

To **disable** a service
`sudo systemctl disable <service-name.service>`

To **enable** a service
`sudo systemctl enable <service-name.service>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sebastian. Please excuse me but how can I add the .svg file to my message? Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways... the easiest... go to https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png and convert it into png o jpg. Then use the normal way to upload an image in your post. Also if you want to see it and you dont have any program, a browser can open it, like Chrome.